# If $f(x)+g(x)$ is strictly concave, then is $x+(g \circ f^{-1})(x)$ also strictly concave?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

Suppose I have continuous, single variable functions $f$ and $g$ : $\mathbb{R\rightarrow}\mathbb{R}$ (both are twice continuously differentiable). Define $H$ as follows

$$H(x)=f(x)+g(x)$$

I know that $H(x)$ is strictly concave. Now suppose that $f$ is invertible and its inverse $f^{-1}$ is twice cont. differentiable everywhere. Define a new $\hat{H}$ as follows

$$\hat{H}(x)=x+(g \circ f^{-1})(x)$$

Is $\hat{H}$ concave in $x$?

---

Since both $g$ and $f^{-1}$ are twice continuously differentiable, so too then is $(g \circ f^{-1})(x)$. Hence we may inspect the sign of $\hat{H}''$. $\hat{H}''$ is  given by

$$\hat{H}''=\frac{g'' \circ f^{-1}}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}-\bigg(\frac{(g' \circ f^{-1})(f''(x))}{\big(f'(f^{-1}(x))\big)^3}\bigg)$$

which is concave if

$$\frac{g'' \circ f^{-1}}{g' \circ f^{-1}}<\frac{f''(x)}{\big[f'(f^{-1}(x))\big]^2}$$

Is there some insight that would simplify the checking of the sign, or is the answer only accessible through laborious computing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $a(x)=x+e^x$, which two times differentiable, strictly convex, invertible and $a'(x)\geq 1$, so $f(x):=a^{-1}(x)$ is two times differentiable, strictly concave and invertible. Further define $g(x)=x$.

Then $H(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is strictly concave but $\hat H(x)=x+g\circ f^{-1}(x)=x+a(x)=2x+e^x$ is strictly convex.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on how you found this example?

Comment: First, $H$ is strictly concave, but not necessarily $f$ and $g$. So if thought, I cancel $g$ by choosing $g(x)=x$. Next, $f$ has to be strictly concave, so $H$ is strictly concave, but then $f^{-1}$ is strictly convex, so $\hat H(x)=x+f^{-1}(x)$ is strictly convex too.  So I just needed to find an invertible strictly convex or concave function and I found $x+e^x$ by trying some examples.

Comment: Are you considering $a(x)$ as the function $f$? If so, I don't see how $x+g\circ f^{-1}(x)=x+a(x)=2x+e^x$? Would it not be $x+a^{-1}(x) = 2x-W(e^x)$ (where $W$ is the Lambert W function (which gives the inverse of some exp function)?

Comment: If you read carefully: I defined $f(x)=a^{-1}(x)$, hence $f^{-1}(x)=a(x)$. _(Somehow it was much easier to find a strictly convex and invertible function than to find a strictly concave invertible function)_

Comment: In fact, My arguments don't need an explicit formula for $f$ or $f^{-1}$. It is sufficient to claim, that $f$ is two times differentiable, invertible strictly convex such that $f^{-1}$ is two times differentiable. Then to arguments go on. But I gave an example to show that there exists such a function $f$.